# GRAPH.FACEBOOOK returns empty array

Tags: python, facebook, email, pdf, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get invoices from a business account using the method : business_invoices
I tried with system user, my user. Both having full admin access and FINANCE_EDITOR but I kepp getting

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

The company that owns the business account has been confirmed.
Invoices is present in the billing, but they are not in the API answer. I turned app to live version and still nothing. I searched their api docs but no luck. : /
Here is debug information:

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<business_id>/business_invoices?access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "manage_fundraisers",
      "read_insights",
      "publish_video",
      "catalog_management",
      "pages_manage_cta",
      "pages_manage_instant_articles",
      "pages_show_list",
      "read_page_mailboxes",
      "ads_management",
      "ads_read",
      "business_management",
      "pages_messaging",
      "pages_messaging_subscriptions",
      "leads_retrieval",
      "page_events",
      "pages_read_engagement",
      "pages_manage_metadata",
      "pages_read_user_content",
      "pages_manage_ads",
      "pages_manage_posts",
      "pages_manage_engagement"
    ],
    "user_id": <user_id>,
    "app_id": <app_id>
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters


  {}
- POST Parameters


  {}
==== Response
  {
    "data": []
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=<busssnise_id>Fbusiness_invoices&version=v16.0
```

I tried everything I could think off and searched the web,but couldnt find the anwser.
I need your help stackoverflow! So future generations of this api call see this and solve this problem quickly.
Sorry for my bad english. Thank you for your time <3